# How to extend/override Rest EntityResource Plugin in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I would like to extend/override the Rest EntityResource Plugin in Drupal 8.  I have read everything I can find online and I can see how to create a resource plugin for something other than an Entity (such as dblog).  However, I can't figure out how to extend/override the existing Entity resource plugin.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working I needed to:

1. Install the Rest UI module.
2. Go to /admin/config/services/rest and
   enable my new resource.
3. Also at /admin/config/services/rest, click the edit button next to the new resource and configure it.
4. Go to /admin/people/permissions and configure the permissions for the new resource (Access GET, Access POST, etc.)

Couple of notes...  Both on the Rest UI config and permissions pages, it was difficult to distinguish between my new resource and the original.  In addition, when I tried to disable the original resource from the Rest UI config page I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Drupal\restui\Controller\drupal_valid_token() in drupal-8.0.0-beta2/modules/contrib/restui/src/Controller/RestUIController.php on line 211
```

However, even though both resources are configured, the system appears to be using my resource and not the original.

Comment: There is a patch for the error when disabling resources: https://www.drupal.org/node/2355807